# Pythonanywhere not able to load static files during deploying django app

Tags: django, web-deployment

Pythonanywhere not able to load my static files during deploying but everything works fine on my local computer.

- Here is the directory structure of my app and settings of static
  file on my local pc:
- https://www.screencast.com/t/l0d6ehWWJ
  and the
  **settings file** contains  STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT =
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static").
- the URL and DIRECTORY on pythonanywhere are as below
- URL-/static/
- DIRECTORY-'/home//Myapp/static'
- here is the image that shows all staticfiles have been copied to static folder https://www.screencast.com/t/p1w1qRz4y

  what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you follow the given steps [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/) from the beginning, it should work.

Comment: @fxgx i followed that link to deploy but still i am not able to figure out the mistake

Comment: I think you are setting the `path` wrong in pythonanywhere dashboard. it should be something like `/home/username/projectname/static`. From the image you uploaded, i can tell that the DIRECTORY should be `/home/ashwini0808/Quiz-app/static`